# How to cutomize 404 page in X-Cart?

Tags: x-cart

I've been searching for quite sometime and scratching my head trying to figure out how to customize xcart's default 404 page. I need the 404 page to go on with my site's custom theme and layout(like menu, recently viewed products section, footer etc) and not with the default theme. Is there any way by which I can do it? It would be of great help if someone could suggest some good solutions.

The xcart version that I'm using is x-cart 4.7.5(Platinum)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two types of X-Cart - X-Cart 4 and X-Cart 5. Their codebase is very different. I advise mentioning your X-Cart version.

Anyways:
In X-Cart 4 https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:404_Error_Page
In X-Cart 5 - two ways: direct editing of 404 page template as explained at http://devs.x-cart.com/en/webinars_and_video_tutorials/editing_templates_on_the_example_of_adding_market_price_to_products_list_in_x-%D1%81art_5_tutorial_by_mike_white.html or using so-called "Webmaster mode" http://devs.x-cart.com/en/webinars_and_video_tutorials/using_webmaster_mode_in_x-cart_5.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question specifying the version.

Comment: Now regarding the links provided, I've already tried this one( https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:404_Error_Page ) as it is the one recommended for the version that I'm using. Now, the issue I'm facing is, I've recently viewed products section, footer etc which are all .tpl files and this error file is an HTML one.

Comment: hello, you have to copy-n-paste styles from your tpls to the file ./skin/<your_skin>/404/404_en.html